# check if dialog contains any of prohibited keywords android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sqlite

I have database table that contains some words "prohibited keywords" and I am letting the user to enter his opinion about my service through Android application.

I want to show an error message if the user enter any of the prohibited keywords in the text of the review and not allowing him to post his review.

The keywords are stored in a SQLite database.

If there any library that can help please advice? Basically I want to know how to do that without splitting user text and search for each word in database, I need an optimized way to do that.

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: how to do that without splitting user text and search for each word in database, I need optimized way to do that

Comment: what do you consider optimized

Comment: maybe use `String#contains()`. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Maybe you should consider posting some code.

Comment: @ZeekHuge but this will make me for loop on each row of my database keywords and check if the string contains the word or not, if I have thousand work, it will take time and processing, is there any better way

Comment: loop through the "user review" and when you come across a prohibited word display your error, also, by now you should be aware that you need to upload your code along with your question so the community can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the text that the user inputs as a String. Then use the String.split(" ") method on the inputted text to create a String array where each element is 1 word. Now loop through the String array, and check if any of the words match any of the prohibited keywords. Addressing your comment saying "without splitting the user text and search for each word in the database", well this is a viable option that could be used.

Another option would be to read the prohibited keywords from the database into a String array. Loop over the array and use the `indexOf(String)` method to see if the inputted string contains any of the prohibited keywords. If indexOf returns -1, that means the string is not found (no prohibited keywords are found). You can do something like this:

```
for (String str : prohibitedStrList) {
    // inputtedStr is from the dialog box that user entered
    if (inputtedStr.indexOf(String str) != -1) {
        // throw your error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution how to achieve what you want:

Retrieve your prohibitive words from your database when the user starts editing, this saves you the time of making more than one call to the database.

Store the words in a HashSet. In case you don't know a HashSet works as an HashMap but without the values, only with keys, meaning there are no repetitive entries.

Add a `TextWatcher` to your EditText, and in `afterTextChanged`, once you get a blank space, meaning the user hit space button, get the length of your Editable, from backwards find the next empty space (by other words, get the last introduced word). This prevents you from cycling the String from the start, you only do it for the last characters.

Once you done this and you have the last word introduced just do this simple verification:

```
if(!myHashSet.add(myStringWord)) //This means the word is present inside your prohibitive words HashSet
    showErrorMessageForProhibitiveWord();
```